# What is a good name for tests in pre-commit hooks?

Tags: testing

I want to help a team of developers implement a system for running tests after a long running build or before commiting to a repository. These tests are often unit tests, but also contain a lot of integration tests. Therefore neither name is suitable. Regression test is also bad, because we already interpret that term as the kind of complicated suite that takes hours to run every night. Is there another name to call this kind of fast pre-commit tests? What is the software testing jargon for that?

Comment: For now I choose "instant test" ala instant noodles, fast but not as good. A real term that is used by the community would be preferable, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the BVT term (Build verification test) or BAT (Build Acceptance Test).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_verification_test

I have faced with this name when we used the pre-commit testing procedure.

*edit by @erikb85*: Reading this Wikipedia article which leads to the article about [smoke testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_%28software%29). Therefore **smoke testing** seems to be the better choice for this term in general.

Comment: What do you think about [smoke testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_%28software%29) seems to be a little more general than BVT and therefore works better with my current situation. If you can add it to your response, I'll mark yours as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is any widely use name. but do you over complicate? can't you just call them 'pre-commit tests'?

Comment: This would have been better as a comment than an answer.